# ng-serve command opens editor

Tags: javascript, angular, ubuntu

I set up a fresh angular-app and try to serve it with

```
ng serve --watch
```

instead of serving the app a file-editor opens. Why does that happen? How can I resolve this?

[this is the editor that shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ww2.png)

Serving with

```
npm start
```

works fine

Comment: what happens if you just use `ng`as a command? maybe there's another software or alias that also listens to the ng command

Comment: the same thing happens, the editor opens

Comment: how can I remove this software and restore ng as the angular command?

Comment: that's probably tricky, which OS are you on? usually there are commands to find out where the source of the software is something like `which ng` on Linux

Comment: I'm on ubuntu, in a vagrant box. 
which ng shows "/usr/bin/ng"

Comment: have you installed ng globally with npm? something like `npm install -g ng`

Comment: I used "npm install -g @angular/cli" to install angular
it worked for a while.

Comment: yeah I meant that, sorry. For a workaround right now you could try the full path of the cli that is placed in the `node_modules` folder, so something like `./node_modules/.bin/ng serve/`

Comment: that works :)
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by

- unistalling the editor that took the ng-alias
- uninstalling angular-cli
- reinstalling angular-cli
- manually adding the angular-cli alias

Answer (score 10):

**Solution :**

Just use npx before any nodejs executables.

Eg :  **`npx ng serve -o`**

Comment: This is the way. Ng would always open notepad ++. I uninstalled notepad++ then the windows app selector would always popup asking me how I would like to open this file. Not sure what happened but seems like a windows issue. NPX solved it. Hope this answer helps others

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how I got there, but suddenly `ng serve` behaved differently and opened the `ng.js` file, in the default editor app actually called `Editor`. I run a Windows-11 OS.

I fixed the problem by going going to the environment variables menu, removing one of the values for the PATH variable.
I removed the following lin, which pointed to my Angular JS:

`C:\path\to\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the angular cli path from your environment variables
2. Run `npm config get prefix` in your cmd or powershell
3. Enter the path you get from step 2 into your path environment variable

> Dont forget to restart your console